# Lenovo T60 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS hard drive problem

Tags: boot

I have been running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for better than a year on my Lenovo T60.  All was fine until I got some errors when booting.  The errors are:

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/..../on root failed: invalid arg
mount: mounting /dev /root/dev failed: no such file/dir 
same on /sys, /proc
target filesystem des nt have requested /sbin/init
No init found try passing init=bootarg
```

So I do a little research and find the commands for `fdisk -1` from the LiveCD and that is where things go from bad to worse.

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS CD is scratched and useless.  So I download the 12.04 LTS from the source and attempt to burn it to a CD.  Too big.  I make a USB image.  It wont boot on my T60, no error messages that I can see, just hangs.  I find a friend who has a DVD burner.  I burn an iso of the 12.04 image.  It boots on the machine it was burned on but not mine.  It starts to boot, I get the black screen and the the small rectangle at the bottom of the screen, that clears and then nothing.

So, I am running out of ideas.  I could buy a 12.04 LTS CD, but I am beginning to wonder if that would boot.  Anyone have any ideas or have seen similar results.  I would really like to fix my drive and get back to Ubuntu'ing.

Comment: Man, that's so sad. Have you tried 13.10?

Comment: No, I might have to give that a try.